# concurrent futures jobs not submitted

Tags: python

I'm trying to use concurrent futures using the below example but my job never gets submitted. Don't see the print stmt in load_url.

```
import sys
from concurrent import futures
import multiprocessing
import time
import queue


def load_url(url,q):
    # it will take 2 seconds to process a URL
    print('load_url')
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        # put some dummy results in queue
        for x in range(5):
            print('put in queue')
            q.put(x)
    except Exception as e:
        print('exception')


def main():
    print('start')
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    e = manager.Event()
    q = queue.Queue()
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        livefutures = {executor.submit(load_url, url, q): url
                       for url in ['a','b']}
        runningfutures = True
        print('check_futures')
        while runningfutures:
            print('here')
            runningfutures = [f for f in livefutures if f.running()]
            if not runningfutures:
                print('not running futures == ', q.empty())
                while not q.empty():
                    print('not running futures1')
                    yield q.get(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in main():
        print('x=',x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late but I just ran into your post.
ProcessPoolExecutor is a bit picky, it requires the treads to execute simple functions and also sometimes behaves differently on Windows and Linux.
ThreadPoolExecutor is more permissive.
If you replace futures.ProcessPoolExecutor by futures.ThreadPoolExecutor it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing python's standard Queue to your asyncronous processes rather than a multiprocessing-safe Queue implementation. Therefore, your asyncronous job is failing with: `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object`. However, because you are not calling `.result` on the future object - this exception is never raised in the main process.

Instantiate your queue with `manager.Queue()` and the code works.